# Instantly reboot a Windows Computer?

Tags: windows

I want to instantly reboot a Windows Computer.
Note that i dont mean the "shutdown" command or anything like that, I want an
instant reboot just like "reboot -f" on linux.
No shutdown. No bluescreen (I tried that, but takes too long to get all the error information). Just instant gone and restart. Is there any way to do that?
I dont really care about the programming Language, it should be just a program that when started will reboot. 
Of course I have administrator permissions, because something like this will probably need them.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why can't you use the "shutdown" command? What is it about that way of rebooting that you don't like?

Comment: Its that it takes to long. Because im testing alot, and i want to be able to quickly reset the PC.

Comment: The best solution is to not write code that crashes the system so much. Alternatively, perhaps you can use a Virtual Machine to test with.